# Very Weird Memory Leak With ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

Good afternoon,

I was doing some Instruments testing on my iOS app that I'm about to release, but I noticed some **VERY** strange memory leaks, that appear to be coming from System libraries.

When I ran Instruments I got this leak: 
[image]

Which is extremely weird from my point of view! I went to the Call Tree of these leaks and they all appear to be deep C++ system calls.

[image]

What confuses me even more is that this project has ARC enabled, and I ran it through the Analyzer and no problems showed up.
Even more weird is that this DOES NOT happen on the Simulator, nor on my real iPad, but on my iPhone this problem happens.

And when I check "Show Obj-C only" and "Hide System Libraries" the call trace disappears which leads me to believe my code is not responsible for the leak.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks guys.

Comment: I am going to disappoint you: Apple's code is not bugfree. There may be memory leaks in the C++ standard library, indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But one thing that still puzzles me is, if that's the case ( that Apple's code has memory leaks)  wouldn't this also appear on the iPad Instruments run?

Comment: I wouldn't beat myself up over this too much. Like @H2CO3 said, Apple's libraries aren't perfect. It wouldn't be the first time a memory leak is found in one of their libraries. It happens quite a lot, actually.

Comment: @user1274223 What revision of iPad and iPhone are you testing with? If you're testing with an iPhone 5 and an older iPad, it could be that the library compiled for armv7x has a bug in it, while the one for armv7 is fine.

Comment: Thanks @SimonGermain, it's just that yesterday I worked really hard to get my code leak free, since I was having a different leak problem ( which I did end up solving), and although it's a small leak that is happening here, I want my app to be leak free.

Comment: the iPhone is a 4S running iOS 5.1.1 and the iPad is an iPad2 running iOS 6.0.1 I believe.( I know it's iOS6 I'm just not 100% sure what exact version of iOS6)

Comment: I understand you wanting your code to be leak free. At the same time, you can't fix code you don't have access to. I'm not sure what kind of numbers we are talking about here, as far as iOS 5.1 devices usage.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, the only problem I see is that apple might reject it for leaking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above leak is not a leak inside your app and it is inside apple's library which you dont have to worry about. If you have fixed all the leaks inside your app, you are fine. Apple will not reject your app just because of this small leak.